# What is the function of Plus button (﹢) in Apple Podcasts app for iOS?

Tags: ios, podcasts

I am using the Apple Podcasts app on my iPhone. Say I subscribe to a podcast and it's status changes from *Subscribe* to *Subscrib**ed***.

[image]

Now when I go to browse the list of all the episodes for the podcast, they appear with a Plus button (﹢) shown to the right which looks like this:

[image]

Tapping the Plus button (﹢) changes it to a download button which looks like this:

[image]

Tapping which the episode gets downloaded for offline access and the button icon disappears.

Taping anywhere else on the episode item without tapping on the Plus button (﹢) streams it over the Internet.

So I am curious to know what function does the Plus button (﹢) serve here?

Apple's support document, [Listen with Apple Podcasts](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201859) mentions only this:

> #### How to download episodes
>
> 1. Find an episode in your library, or browse or search for an episode.
> 2. Tap or click the download button [image] next to the episode's name. Or, if you see the add button [image], tap or click it, then tap or click the download button [image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plus button (﹢) is used to add an individual episode to the Library. Once added the episode becomes available under the Library and the Listen Now tab.

[image] [image]